# About Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION lifecycle

Tags: android, android-intent

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html  As the document said
   **Permissions granted in an Intent remain in effect while the stack of the receiving Activity is active. When the stack finishes, the permissions are automatically removed. Permissions granted to one Activity in a client app are automatically extended to other components of that app.**
2. To test the flag, in our application, we got a Activity (Activity A) to receive the shared image from google photo，and we get the image uri(content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F402643/REQUIRE_ORIGINAL/NONE/135827760)，and Activity A send the uri to another Activity (Activity B),
   Activity A finished itself immediately，then the Activity B postDelayed 5 second to resolve the uri，the resolve method is below

   ```
   ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
   ```
3. As the document said，the Activity B should has the permission to resolve the uri too. But，in Activity B，I got an exception:

   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{2d1e8e3 16688:com.linghan.devdemo/u0a513} (pid=16688, uid=10513) that is not exported from UID 10079

But the same code in Activity A is fine.

How to explain the permission lack in Activity B?

Comment: Did you find any solution?